# How to make map with overlaid column charts using highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Highmaps provides a way to implement map with overlaid pie charts, is there a way to change `pie` with `column`?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-pies/

Comment: While there is surely a way, it's not a simple matter of changing a configuration option. That's a series of custom functions to define how and where the `pie` charts are created that will need to be re-worked to create column charts.

Comment: @jlbriggs hi, I see that they have made a new series called mappie which has center specifications and size formatter, and I was thinking to implement same with column , but I cant find mappie in maps.js or highchart.js scripts, can you please help me locate it?

Comment: @jlbriggs when I change the 'mappie' series with simple pie ,the the charts are creating , but the centers specifications are not working , as it was added in mappie series .

Comment: As far as I can see, they have not created a series type within the library, they are aliasing the pie series type under the name `mappie` strictly within the functions in the fiddle. Change the name from `mappie` to anything else, and it still works the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mappie` series is not a part of Highcharts core. It is a custom series created with Highcharts.seriesType function (you can find it here: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js) at the beginning of the demo. You can modify provided example and create series such as `mapcolumn`. Although, map is not very readable and tooltip does not work correctly when rendering columns instead of pies. You give it a try and create your own custom series.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wsuhws7c/