# Draw a column chart like a legend in a high chart map

Tags: highcharts

hi~ Please understand if it doesn't fit the form because it's the first question

I'm drawing a map using a high chart map and I want to put a column chart in a specific location, does anyone know if it's possible? From what I looked for, I found an example of drawing a pie chart using map points (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/map-pies)

I wonder if it's possible to draw in column charts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KSlS.png)

thx!

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/map-pies

In that example, I switched the pie chart to a column, but it didn't appear in a specific location, and it covered the entire map

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not supported in Highcharts by default but can be relatively easily achievable by custom code. My example below is using the default column series and additional, hidden axes to draw all columns in one place. Then, columns are translated to specific positions on the map.

```
Highcharts.seriesType('mapcolumn', 'column', {}, {
  drawPoints: function() {
    // Proceed
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawPoints.call(this);
    // Custom      
    var series = this,
      points = series.points,
      firstSeries = series.chart.series[0];

    Highcharts.each(points, function(point, index) {
      var state = firstSeries.points[series.index - 3];
      var newX = state.plotX + index * COLUMN_WIDTH - COLUMN_WIDTH;
      var newY = state.plotY - point.graphic.attr('height') + 10;

      point.tooltipPos[0] = newX;
      point.tooltipPos[1] = newY;

      point.graphic.attr({
        x: newX,
        y: newY,
        width: COLUMN_WIDTH
      });
    });
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8pdxuebk/

**Useful thread:** [How to make map with overlaid column charts using highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713124/how-to-make-map-with-overlaid-column-charts-using-highmaps)

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts